# Is Jupyter notebook removed from list of languages in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Recently I have updated **VS Code** to the version **1.70.2**.

I am encountering following problem: after I create a new file, I want to select the language.
I am looking to select `Jupyter` notebooks (Python). Normally I would press `Ctrl K M`  and the drop down menu appeared, from which I was able to select `Jupyter` (the file extension .ipynb)

Now I cannot find `Jupyter` in list of defaults (I search using both word Jupyter and the extension). Where is it? How Can I add `Jupyter` back to the list of default choices in VS Code?
I could save a file and then rename it with Jupiter extension, but it is annoying!

Comment: When you create a new file VSC give you the choice to choose the file type or to choose a different text editor. To create a Jupyter notebook you have to choose the second option and select Jupyter. otherwise maybe idiot question but did you install the Jupyter extension ?

Comment: Thank you! I have checked and there is Jupyter! (yes I have the extension.) It was different in previous version of VSC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence: I have update my VS Code from version **1.5-ish** to recent **1.70.2**. Previously, a new text file was created and all you had to do is to click `Ctrl + K M` and select `Jupyter` from drop-down menu.
Now a new text file has a message *Select a language or open a different editor to get started*. To get `Jupyter` one has to click on *open a different editor* and select `Jupyter Notebook`.